# Зацикливание алгоритма выпадения случайной монеты

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, while

Решил написать "простейшую" програму - симулятор подброса монеты.

Одной из функций -  подброс монеты **n**-е количество раз. 
Воспользовался циклом `while n`, где (**n** число подбросов), но программа выдает бесконечное число результатов. Как от этого избавится?

```
import random

def coin():
    n = int(input('Введите число:'))
    while n:
        x = random.randint(1, 2)
        if x == 1:
            print ('Орел')
        else:
            print ('Решка')


coin()
```

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 16):

```
def coin():
    n = int(input('Введите число:'))
    while n:
        x = random.randint(1, 2)
        if x == 1:
            print ('Орел')
        else:
            print ('Решка')
        n -= 1
coin()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import random as rnd

def coin():
    for i in range(int(input())):
        x = rnd.randint(1, 2)
        print('Орёл' if 1 == x else 'Решка')

coin()
```

Answer (score 2):

Используем randint в 8 раз меньше:

```py
import random

def myfunc(b):
    x = random.randint(0, 2**b - 1)
    for _ in range(b):
        print('Орёл' if x&1 else 'Решка')
        x >>= 1

def coin():
    n = int(input("N = ? "))
    b = 8
    nq, nr = n // b, n % b
    for _ in range(nq):
        myfunc(b)
    myfunc(nr)

coin()
```